# Fraction: как сложить дробь с целым числом?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Реализовал класс Fraction для операций с дробями.

```
def gcd(a, b):

    while a % b != 0:
        old_a = a
        old_b = b

        a = old_b
        b = old_a % old_b

    return b

class Fraction:

    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

    def __repr__(self):
        return '{}/{}'.format(self.a, self.b)

    def __add__(self, other):
        if not isinstance(self, Fraction):
            return NotImplemented

        new_a = self.a * other.b + \
        self.b * other.a
        new_b = self.b * other.b
        common = gcd(new_a, new_b)

        return Fraction(new_a // common, new_b // common)
```

> Input: print(Fraction(10, 5) + Fraction(10, 5))
>
> Output: 4/1
>
> Input: print(Fraction(10, 5) + 1)
>
> Output: **AttributeError:** 'int' object has no attribute 'b'

Вопрос: как сложить дробь с целым числом?

Comment: Можете предоставить полный код класса?

Comment: Дополнил в первом посте.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
def __add__(self, other):
    if not isinstance(self, Fraction):
        return NotImplemented

    if isinstance(other, Fraction):
        other_a, other_b = other.a, other.b
    elif isinstance(other, int):
        other_a, other_b = other, 1
    else:
        return NotImplemented

    new_a = self.a * other_b + self.b * other_a
    new_b = self.b * other_b
    common = gcd(new_a,new_b)

    return Fraction(new_a // common, new_b // common)
```

Comment: `__radd__ = __add__`

Comment: Огромное спасибо! До такого бы я не додумался.